# Problem with public key, when i use mapquest directions service?

Tags: mapquest

I recently registered in mapquest service and get api key, then i tried to use make request to directions service, but get following response:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback12({
    "route": {
        "routeError": {
            "message": "",
            "errorCode": 3
        }
    },
    "info": {
        "copyright": {
            "text": "© 2013 MapQuest, Inc.",
            "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
            "imageAltText": "© 2013 MapQuest, Inc."
        },
        "statuscode": 403,
        "messages": ["This is not a valid key. Please check that you have entered this correctly. If you do not have a key, you can obtain a free key by registering at http://developer.mapquest.com."]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In fixing the same error I found that I was sending the URL encoded key.

Per the Python documentation:

```
urllib.unquote(string)

Replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent. Example:
unquote('/%7Econnolly/') yields '/~connolly/'.
```

Unencoding the key string solved my problem.